# Is there a way to declare all the values in the list as a list individually in python

Tags: python, arrays, syntax

I have a list a[i,j,k]. Out of this, I need to iterate through list 'a' and declare each of the list items as a list separately.

```
    i[]  
    j[]  
    k[]
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: What do you even mean by "a list a[i,j,k]" or "declare each of the list items as a list separately"?

Comment: "Declare" in the context of programming usually means "to indicate the type of a variable". But Python has implicit typing. In other words, you never need to declare anything. So it's not clear to me what you're asking, here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, it is a requirement here that your question be clear and complete. When asked a question in a comment, you should answer it. You now have two questions that you need to answer. Frankly, I do not understand your question either.

Comment: what i meant to ask was if there was a way to create a separate array out of the elements of the existing list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

loop through and create

```
for item in a:
    item = []
```

or you can use list comprehension

```
a = [[] for item in a]
```

if your intended output is `[[i], [j], [k]]` then use

```
a = [[item] for item in a]
```